# Advantage of the hugetlbfs over flag MAP_HUGETLB

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap, huge-pages

I've been reading the Linux Kernel [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) about huge pages. What I understand from the section `Using Huge Pages` there are 3 ways how to get them:

1. The SHM POSIX API
2. By using the `MAP_HUGETLB` flag in `mmap` parameters
3. Open file at the `hugetlbfs` and map it through `mmap`

The SHM is useful when I need some shared memory between multiple processes.

The disadvantage of the `hugetlbfs` is that I have to provide a path to the mounted `hugetlbfs`. While with the simple flag `MAP_HUGETLB` I don't need this information. So what is the advantage of using the `hugetlbfs`?